# Stored float value in string .. unable to convert it to integer

Tags: android, type-conversion

I have a string value which ids getting from JSON. Value is like 10.95. But i want to convert it to Integer. How can I convert?

Comment: please put your code

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to convert directly to Integer.Use `Math.round()` before typecasting using `(int)` should round the float to the nearest whole number.

```
int value =(int)(Math.round(Float.valueOf("10.95")));
```

Comment: Then it will get the output for value is 10.... But I am getting 10.95 from the JSON I want to store that value in db

Comment: @yamuna okay.change data type of that column;

Comment: @yamuna SQLite supports only these `1.) NULL 2.) BLOB 3.) INTEGER 4.) REAL 5.) TEXT` data types.Use `REAL` data type.